# Extract the first two words from a string with C#

Tags: c#

I guys im trying to workout C# code to extract the first two words from string. below is code im doing.

```
public static string GetDetailsAsString(string Details)
    {


        string Items = //how to get first 2 word from string??? 

       if (Items == null || Items.Length == 0)
           return string.Empty;
       else
           return Items;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? How are your words separated ? If you iterate through the String character by character or use `split()`, this is quite straightforward

Comment: Welcome to SO! While people here are pleased to help out, please take the tour first! We want you to put in some effort and try first before asking!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the words are separated by whitespaces:

```
var WordsArray=Details.Split(); 
string Items = WordsArray[0] + ' ' + WordsArray[1];
```

Answer (score 11):

Define "words", if you want to get the first two words that are separated by white-spaces you can use `String.Split` and `Enumerable.Take`:

```
string[] words = Details.Split();
var twoWords = words.Take(2);
```

If you want them as separate string:

```
string firstWords = twoWords.First();
string secondWord = twoWords.Last();
```

If you want the first two words as single string you can use `String.Join`:

```
string twoWordsTogether = string.Join(" ", twoWords);
```

Note that  this simple approach will replace new-line/tab characters with empty spaces.

Comment: Depending on the input size, `String.Split()` might be inappropriate, because it generates a whole array of substrings. Looking for the second occurence of `" "` should be both faster and more memory-friendly.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: we don't know enough about his requirement and the expected input string. There are more issues with `Split`,`Take`,`Join` than that (as mentioned). Performance is not a problem until it became one ;)

Comment: And what possible requirement or expectation would make the `Split()` approach more appropriate than looking for white spaces? I think that it is quite obvious that `Details` contains some kind of text. As long as there are more than two words (and even then), `Split()` does more than needs to be done.

Comment: thanks for the response !! my input is a text field that has been pass in to this method . Text can be anything that user enter into that textfield